# Cramer's rule doesn't work in this case. Why?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Here I have these equations,
x + y + z = 2,
2x + 3y + 2z = 5,
2x + 3y + 15z = 5
When solving normally, we get (x,y,z) = (1,1,0) but when used cramer's rule, we get
Delta = 0 , Delta x = 13, Deltta y = 13, Delta z = 0. It means that the given system of equation is inconsistent. How can this be possible?

EDIT : Determinant is not 0, it's 13. I just wrote the terms wrong when calculating :p

Comment: If Delta is the determinant of the matrix of the coefficients of the system, then it is $13$, not $0$.

Comment: No you are wrong, when two columns in a matrix are same the determinant is 0

Comment: And which two columns are equal?

Comment: 1st and 2nd. You can just find the determinant normally you will get 0. It's just a property I remember.

Comment: Oh I Just realised I was wrong about it. Sorry

Comment: Indeed $2\ne3$.

Comment: Yeah xD, I don't know why I took them the same

Comment: I'm sorry Mr.José Carlos Santos

Answer (score 2):

$$\Delta=\det\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 3 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 15 \\
\end{array}
\right)=13$$
and
$$\Delta_x=\det\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 1 & 1 \\
 5 & 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 3 & 15 \\
\end{array}
\right)=13$$
To solve with Cramer's rule you must do
$$x=\frac{\Delta_x}{\Delta}=\frac{13}{13}=1$$
And so on for the other unknowns

Comment: Yeah Thank You. I just did the determinant wrong for some reason.